# Linux clean directory script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ls

I need to write a script for a web server that will clean out files/folders older than 14 days, but keep the last 7 files/directories.  I've been doing my research so far and here is what I came up with (I know the syntax and commands are incorrect but just so you get an idea):

```
ls -ldt /data/deployments/product/website.com/*/ | tail -n +8 | xargs find /data/deployments/product/website.com/ -type f -type d -mtime +14 -exec rm -R {} \;
```

This is my thought process as to how the script should behave (I'm more a windows batch guy):

**List the directory contents**

```
 If contents is less than or equal to 7, goto END
 If contents is > 7 goto CLEAN
:CLEAN
ls -ldt /data/deployments/product/website.com/*/
keep last 7 entries (tail -n +8)
output of that "tail" -> find -type f -type d (both files and directories) -mtime +14 (not older than 14 days) -exec rm -R (delete)
```

I've seen a bunch of examples, using xargs and sed but I just can't figure out how to put it all together.

Comment: What determines what are the 7 kept files?

Comment: You should probably look at `logrotate`.

Comment: "clean out files/folders older than 14 days, but keep the last 7 files/directories" Does this mean: "keep the file if its age is less than 14 days OR if it's one of the 7 latest files in the directory"?

Comment: It means there must be at LEAST 7 directories within the specified location. If there are more than 7, clean out the oldest ones, up to 14 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

find you_dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | \
sort -nrk1,1 |sed '1,7d' | cut -d' ' -f2 | \
xargs -n1 -I fname \
find fname -maxdepth 0 -mtime +14 -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

remove the `echo` if your happy with the output...

Explanation (line-by-line):

1. `find` in exactly in `your_dir` and print seconds_since_Unix_epoch (`%T@`) and file(/dir)name for each file/dir on a separate line
2. sort by first field (seconds_since_Unix_epoch) descending, throw the first seven lines away - from the rest extract just the name (second field)
3. `xargs` passes on to new `find` process argument-by-argument (`-n1`) and uses `fname` to represent argument
4. `-maxdepth 0` limits `find` to just `fname`

You could store the minNrOfFiles and the ageLimit in Bash-Variables or pass in to the script with just few changes:

```
minNrOfFiles=7 # or $1
ageLimit=14    # or $2
```

change: `sed '1,'"$minNrOfFiles"'d'` and `-mtime +"$ageLimit"`

Comment: Thank you for your script.  However, it is not leaving the 7 directories.  I won't delete everything, but I don't want it to delete things that it shouln't.  For example, the current directory I'm running the script on, it contains 5 files, and 5 directories.  When I run your script, it gives me 3 folders that are indeed older than 14 days. However, the total amount of folders are less than 7, therefore the script shouldn't delete anything.
Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: please read your own question: it states "... keep the last 7 **files/directories** ...". And that is exactly what you report: you have 5 files + 5 dirs (=10 entities) and the script deletes 3 oldest that are older than 14 days (leaving 7)

Comment: Oh I see.  The directories in that path are a result of the tar.gz files, therefore, I need to run two separate scripts:  one script to handle directories and one script to handle files.  How can I edit this script to do this?
Thanks!